# How to filter attributes in expand model due to user priveleges in Yii2 REST API

Tags: php, rest, yii2, filtering, privileges

in example I have ActiveRecords models Client and Invoice.

```php
class Client {
    public function getInvoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class, ['id' => 'invoice_id']);
    }

    public function extraFields() : array
    {
        return ['invoices'];
    }
}
class Invoice
{
    public static function getSuperSecretAttributes()
    {
        // attributes visible only for users with specific RBAC roles
        return ['secret_attribute'];
    }
}
```

My goal is to set "secretAttributes" visible only for users with RBAC role "admin".
Example request to API is:

`http://somehost/clients/1?expand=invoices`

```
{
  "client_id" : 1,
  // ...
  "invoices" : [
      {
          "id" : 1,
          // ...
          "secret_attribute" : "foo"
      }
  ]
}
```

and I got Client model attributes, with expanded Invoices with "secret_attribute" included.
It's easy to filter "secretAttributes" from Client by override `/yii/rest/Serializer::serializeModel()`, example pseudo-code:

```
if (! user-has-role(Rbac::ROLE_ADMIN)) {
    foreach (model::getSuperSecretAttributes() as $attributeName) {
        unset(model[$attributeName]);
    }
}
```

but what to do with secret attributes in related models?
How to filter it out without accessing to session in Model?

Comment: Just extend serializer https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/Serializer.php#L168

Comment: How? There you get only string "invoices", you can filter out whole Invoices models, not chosen Invoice attributes. Access to Invoice attributes is in toArray() method in model, but it's model and shouldn't touch user session.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 is a powerhouse.
All you have to do is overwrite the `fields()` function in your `Invoice` model.

```php
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest || !\Yii::$app->user->can('see-secret-stuff-rule')) {
        unset($fields['secret_invoice'], $fields['other_sensitive_field'] /*, ... */);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```